# How to make Evolution sort email by Date?

Tags: email, evolution, date, email-client

Despite configuring Evolution to sort emails by descending Date, it is not doing it. Note in the attached screenshot how it not only is ascending some emails in the stack it is also mixing up the dates so they aren't even chronological.

Is this fixable? How do I get it to sort emails by descending (chronological) date?

[image: Screenshot-1]
[image: Screenshot-2]